# Axes around image

Tags: plotting

I have the following image (500*430pixels, 8bit, png):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCVJy.png

How can I show axes around (*horizontal data: [1,15]; vertical data: [2,10]*)?

The result should be the following:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
pic = Import["https://i.imgur.com/QVlIq3g.png"];


Graphics[
 Inset[pic, Scaled[{.5, .5}], Automatic, Scaled[1]],
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{1, 15}, {2, 10}},
 AspectRatio -> ImageAspectRatio@pic
]
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you ...

Answer (score 4):

I wrote you a function for this.
It works by explicit setting the option `FrameTicks`.

```
ShowImageWithTicks[img_,xRange_,yRange_]:=Module[{dims=ImageDimensions[img]},Show[img,Frame->True,FrameTicks->{{Partition[Riffle[Range[0,dims[[2]],dims[[2]]/(Length[yRange]-1)],yRange],2],None},{Partition[Riffle[Range[0,dims[[1]],dims[[1]]/(Length[xRange]-1)],xRange],2],None}}]]
```

Which can simply be called with:

```
img=Import["https://i.imgur.com/QVlIq3g.png"];

ShowImageWithTicks[img,Range[1,15,2],Range[2,10]]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Your Labels can simply be introduced by calling to Show and setting `FrameLabel`:

```
Show[ShowImageWithTicks[img,Range[1,15,2],Range[2,10]],FrameLabel->{"time [s]","x [mm]"}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: You're using a `Show` inside of a `Show`. Why not combine it to be more elegant?

Comment: Because its not a complex task to set FrameLabel so i didn't saw the reason to do it. If OP wants to, i'll combine it into a single function with optional parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Assume, `im` is your image. Try this:

```
f[x_] := {(600 x)/8 - 150, x}
g[x_] := {(600*x)/(14), x}; 

    Show[im, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{f[#] & /@ Range[2, 10, 2], None},
        {g[#] & /@ Range[2, 14, 2], None}}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you ... now I understand how to use `FrameTicks` ...

Answer (score 2):

One possibility, use `Show` and turn the axes on with `Axes->True`. A rather crude solution for the ticks would be to scale them as follows (but there are surely more elegant solutions):

```
tx = Table[{500*i, 15*i}, {i, 0, 1, 1/15}];
ty = Table[{430*i, 10*i}, {i, 0, 1, 1/10}];
Show[img, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"time (sec)", "x (mm)"}, 
 Ticks -> {tx, ty}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ... I would like to have different axes values than the pixel numbers (see above).

Answer (score 1):

```
img = Import["https://i.imgur.com/QVlIq3g.png"];

id = ImageDimensions @ img
```

> {500, 430}

```
ticks = {Transpose @ {Subdivide[0, id[[1]], 7], Subdivide[1, 15, 7]}, 
         Transpose @ {Subdivide[0, id[[2]], 4], Subdivide[2, 10, 4]}}

Labeled[Show[img, Axes -> True, Ticks -> ticks],
 {"time (s)", "x (mm)"}, {Bottom, Left}, RotateLabel -> True]
```

[image]

Using `Frame` is more straightforward, but I'm providing a different approach. Additionally, one can define `pl = {{1, 15}, {2, 10}}` and insert specific parts in `ticks` (as well as the number of subdivisions) to make it automated; I'll leave it as it is for clarity.