# Between own axes around ArrayPlot white borders occur

Tags: plotting

I have an `ArrayPlot`:

```
plot = ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {10, 20}], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  Frame -> None]
```

[image]

Now I want to plot axes around the plot labeled with numbers from my own plot range:

```
Graphics[Inset[plot, Scaled[{.5, .5}], Automatic, Scaled[1]], 
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{11.5, 14.5}, {0.4, 0.8}}, 
 AspectRatio -> ImageAspectRatio@plot]
```

I used here the solution from @Kuba in this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131306/axes-around-image).

[image]

**How can I stretch the plot so that it fits into the frame without white borders, preserving the aspect ratio?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For minimal modification to your code zero [`PlotRangePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangePadding.html) and [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html) in the [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html):

```
Graphics[
 Inset[
   Show[plot, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0],
     Scaled[{.5, .5}], Automatic, Scaled[1]
 ]
 , Frame -> True
 , PlotRange -> {{11.5, 14.5}, {0.4, 0.8}}
 , AspectRatio -> ImageAspectRatio @ plot
]
```

[image]

Alternatively construct the needed [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html) in [`ArrayPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPlot.html):

```
rangeFn[{{x_, X_}, {y_, Y_}}, {h_, w_}] :=
   {{x + (X - x)/(2 w), X - (X - x)/(2 w)},
    {y + (Y - y)/(2 h), Y - (Y - y)/(2 h)}}

data = RandomReal[1, {10, 20}];

range = rangeFn[{{11.5, 14.5}, {0.4, 0.8}}, Dimensions@data];

p2 = ArrayPlot[data
      , ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
      , DataRange -> range
      , AspectRatio -> 1/2
      , PlotRangePadding -> None
     ];

Show[p2, FrameTicks -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Notes:

- [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) is necessary here as adding [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html) to the `ArrayPlot` expression does not yield a reasonable tick spacing.
- `rangeFn` is needed to counteract "For ArrayPlot, the settings for DataRange refer to the coordinates of the centers of each cell."

Comment: Thanks  a  lot … but I still see in my `Graphics` output a very small white gap above the lower horizontal axis and also left from the right vertical axis. I am using Mathematica 11.3.0.0

Comment: @Lenoil please try using `Inset[Show[plot, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0], 
 Scaled[{.5, .5}], Automatic, Scaled[1]]` and report the result.

Comment: Mr.Wizard this is the solution … thank you.

Comment: @Lenoil Glad I could help! :-)  I *think* `ImageMargins` is not needed so I left that out of my revised answer; please let me know if this is incorrect.  I also added an alternative approach you may consider.

Comment: I tried both of your solutions and they work as you wrote. Thank you for the notes.

Comment: Could you please have a look on that question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189782/two-data-sets-superposed-using-two-different-axes-styles. I am looking for a solution with pure Mathematica 11.3 commands.

Comment: @mrz I am still using version 10.1.  Are you saying that behavior has changed in 11.3 and the answers to [(627)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/627/121) no longer work as shown?

Answer (score 0):

```
Graphics[
 Inset[plot, Scaled[{.5, .5}], Automatic, Scaled[1.072]],
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRange -> {{11.5, 14.5}, {0.4, 0.8}},
 AspectRatio -> ImageAspectRatio@plot]
```

Comment: Thank you but the factor 1.072 from where did you get it? I need some general solution.