# Two data sets superposed using two different axes styles

Tags: plotting

I saw the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis), but I don't see the right axes labels in Mathematica 11.3.

I have two data sets:

```
data1 = Get@"https://pastebin.com/raw/RDYqjCeA";
data2 = Get@"https://pastebin.com/raw/e3qcivH0";
```

I can plot the data points below each other for optical comparison:

```
minxdata1 = Min[data1[[All, 1]]];
maxxdata1 = Max[data1[[All, 1]]];
minydata1 = Min[data1[[All, 2]]];
maxydata1 = Max[data1[[All, 2]]];

minxdata2 = Min[data2[[All, 1]]];
maxxdata2 = Max[data2[[All, 1]]];
minydata2 = Min[data2[[All, 2]]];
maxydata2 = Max[data2[[All, 2]]];

plot1 = ListPlot[data1, 
   PlotRange -> {{minxdata1, maxxdata1}, {minydata1, maxydata1}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"y data1", ""}, {"x data1", ""}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> Large];

plot2 = ListPlot[data2, 
   PlotRange -> {{minxdata2, maxxdata2}, {minydata2, maxydata2}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"y data2", ""}, {"x data2", ""}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> Large];

GraphicsColumn[{plot1, plot2}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 Spacings -> {{0, 0}, {0, 20}}]
```

[image]

**I would like to plot both data sets in a single plot:**

- left and bottom axes for `data1` (and labels `x data1`, `y data1`) should be in blue with corresponding axes numbers and data points also in blue
- right and upper axes for `data2` (and labels `x data2`, `y data2`) should be in red with corresponding axes numbers and data points also in red

How can this be solved?

Comment: I suggest to look at `MinMax` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rescale `data2` and put everything in a single `ListPlot`:

```
{{minmax1x, minmax1y}, {minmax2x, minmax2y}} = CoordinateBounds /@ {data1, data2};
data2transformed = RescalingTransform[{minmax2x, minmax2y}, {minmax1x, minmax1y}] @ data2;
xticks2 = Charting`FindTicks[minmax1x, minmax2x];
yticks2 = Charting`FindTicks[minmax1y, minmax2y];

ListPlot[{data1, data2transformed}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red},
 Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> {{Blue, Red}, {Blue, Red}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, yticks2 }, {Automatic, xticks2}},
 FrameLabel -> {{"y data1", "y data2"}, {"x data1", "x data2"}},
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "Calibri"},
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> {All, minmax1y}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It might be easier to use the package `SciDraw`: (https://scidraw.nd.edu)

```
<< "SciDraw`"

p1 = ListPlot[data1, 
   PlotRange -> {{minxdata1, maxxdata1}, {minydata1, maxydata1}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"y data1", ""}, {"x data1", ""}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{LinTicks[400, 800, 100, 4], 
      None}, {LinTicks[1500, 1600, 20, 4], None}}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Blue, 15], 
   FrameStyle -> {{Directive[Blue], Null}, {Directive[Blue], Null}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> Large, ImagePadding -> 50];

p2 = ListPlot[data2, 
   PlotRange -> {{minxdata2, maxxdata2}, {minydata2, maxydata2}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"", "y data2"}, {"", "x data2"}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, LinTicks[400, 800, 100, 4]}, {None, 
      LinTicks[0, 80, 20, 4]}}, FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Red, 15],
    FrameStyle -> {{Null, Directive[Red]}, {Null, Directive[Red]}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> Large, ImagePadding -> 50];

Overlay[{p1, p2}]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

To skip `SciDraw`, (using the default ticks)

```
p1 = ListPlot[data1, 
   PlotRange -> {{minxdata1, maxxdata1}, {minydata1, maxydata1}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"y data1", ""}, {"x data1", ""}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {All, None}}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Blue, 15], 
   FrameStyle -> {{Directive[Blue], Null}, {Directive[Blue], Null}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> Large, ImagePadding -> 50];

p2 = ListPlot[data2, 
   PlotRange -> {{minxdata2, maxxdata2}, {minydata2, maxydata2}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"", "y data2"}, {"", "x data2"}}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, All}}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Red, 15], 
   FrameStyle -> {{Null, Directive[Red]}, {Null, Directive[Red]}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> Large, ImagePadding -> 50];

Overlay[{p1, p2}]
```

Comment: This is great. Is this not possible without SciDraw? I am using Mathematica 11.3.

Comment: @mrz SciDraw runs in 11.3, you may ignore the warning messages; it's not exactly necessary, only `LinTicks` is used, which generates a table for the major and minor ticks, you can see how to generate such tables in the documentation, details section in https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html

Comment: @mrz you may also replace the `LinTicks[...]` by `All` and skip SciDraw to use the default tick choices, see my edits

Answer (score 3):

```
plot1 = ListPlot[data1, PlotRange -> (MinMax@data1[[All, 2]] + 10), 
   PlotStyle -> Blue, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"y data1", ""}, {"x data1", ""}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> Large, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Blue], ImagePadding -> 50];

plot2 = ListPlot[data2, PlotRange -> (MinMax@data2[[All, 2]] + 10), 
   PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, True}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"", "y data2"}, {"", "x data2"}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> Large, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Red], ImagePadding -> 50, 
   FrameTicks -> All];

Overlay[{plot1, plot2}]
```

[image]